# Expandir <div> e chamar outro conteúdo de forma assíncrona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como posso criar um evento clique numa `<div>` que ao receber o evento ela expandisse para uma porcentagem da tela.

Ex: 6 `<div>`, blog, quem somos, etc... Quando eu clicar em "Quem somos", ela expande com um CSS diferente, textos, etc... Creio que seja assíncrono, mas não consegui fazer.

OBS: Gostaria de fazer com efeitos de transition.

Comment: experimente [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Cara sua pergunta esta meio confusa, qual porcentagem de tela? Quer que a doce expanda de que forma? Edite a pergunta com uma imagem do layout que pretende ou com o código que já tem

Comment: Tipo assim man https://codepen.io/RobotsPlay/pen/Lniyd

Answer (score 0):

Até dá pra fazer assíncrono, mas na maioria das vezes não é necessário.

Usualmente é feito isso deixando uma `div` escondida que ao clicar na div que tem o título você mostra ou oculta ela, dependendo do estado atual dela.

Vou deixar como exemplo um código simples, mas se quiser algo mais rebuscado sinta-se a vontade para melhorá-lo.

```
<div id="meuId">
    <h1>Seu título</h1>
    <div style="display:none;">
        Sua descrição aqui.
        Você pode usar html e css normalmente.
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // para fazer o conteúdo aparecer e sumir
    $("#meuId h1").click(function(){

        if ($("#meuId div").is(":visible"))
            $("#meuId div").slideUp(500); // fecha a div de baixo pra cima
        else
            $("#meuId div").slideDown(500); // abre a div de cima para baixo

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Valeu man... Eu queria algo nesse modelo >> https://codepen.io/RobotsPlay/pen/Lniyd << saka?? Me ajuda?

Comment: Entendi rs, mas então você já tem o código do que você quer fazer, é só analisar e entender o que ele faz, e então reproduzir do jeito que você quiser. É bom entender em vez de copiar e colar, é a dica que eu dou, pq depois você pode aplicar esses conhecimentos em outra coisa.